# Formating variable results to send with phpmailer

Tags: php, arrays, variables, format, phpmailer

So, I have results to send by phpmail stored in arrays and I'm trying to give it a minimum of format like that:

```
        $results = array();
            array_walk_recursive(
            $texto, //--- contains other 3 arrays: $texto[] = array($date,$speaker,$msg);
            function ($value, $key) use (&$results) {
            $results[] = $value;
            });
            $texto_forma = implode('\n', $results);
```

That's ok to print on the screen, but when I send it with phpmailer like that:

```
            ...
            $texto = "$texto_forma";
    $mail->Body = $texto;
    (!$mail->Send());
```

I'll get a mail with the results like: blablabla\nblablabla\nblablabla instead of having it separated by rows.

What can I use instead of \n ? I've tryeid also 
 obviously with not the expected result

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `nl2br` function which will convert `\n` to `<br\>`

also send the email with mime type as HTML so that it will properly rendered

Comment: Hi! I don't need to convert it, I can just change \n with <br> directly in the code.
I used $mail->isHTML(true); as you suggested and now it works! Thanks a lot!